# Save RGB image (.jpg) to a binary file (.bin) in C++ and Python

Tags: python, c++, image, opencv, binary

I want to save an RGB image (.jpg) to a binary file (.bin) and get the same saved data (in the .bin file) using python and c++.

Here are the codes I used to save the image to a bin file in Python and C++ but I got different results when I compared the two .bin files.

**Python**

```py
image = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
filename1 = "/image.bin"   # save data as bin file
bin_file = image.astype('float32').tofile(filename1)
byte_list = []
with open(filename1, "rb") as f:
    while (byte := f.read(1)):
        byte_list.append(byte)
```

**C++**

```cpp
int IMAGE_SIZE = 224;

void matwrite(const string& filename, const Mat& mat)
{
    ofstream fs(filename, fstream::binary);

    // Header
    int type = mat.type();
    int channels = mat.channels();
    fs.write((char*)&mat.rows, sizeof(int));    // rows
    fs.write((char*)&mat.cols, sizeof(int));    // cols
    fs.write((char*)&type, sizeof(int));        // type
    fs.write((char*)&channels, sizeof(int));    // channels

    // Data
    if (mat.isContinuous())
    {
        fs.write(mat.ptr<char>(0), (mat.dataend - mat.datastart));
    }
    else
    {
        int rowsz = CV_ELEM_SIZE(type) * mat.cols;
        for (int r = 0; r < mat.rows; ++r)
        {
            fs.write(mat.ptr<char>(r), rowsz);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Save data

    {
        cv::Mat noisyImg = cv::imread("image.jpg");
        //randu(m, 0, 5);
        matwrite("bin_file.bin", data);
    }
return 0 ;
}
```

What I'm looking for is to save the RGB image in both c++ and python to a binary file (.bin) with the same method to get matched data saved in both bin files (from python and C++)

Thanks.

Comment: How are the files different? It would help to see an example of the difference, perhaps a couple of lines of hexdump from the beginning of each.

Comment: They are .bin files I compared them using md5sum

Comment: Well, since we do not have access to these files you might have to do some detective work on your own and provide some more details. Are they the same size? Have you diffed them to see what the difference is? Why does your c++ example read the file into a variable named `noisyImg` and then pass a variable that isn't shown in the code named `data` to the `matwrite` function?

Comment: I'm guessing it's the conversion to float on the python script that is causing you problems. Is your c++ matrix also float?

Comment: what *is* the problem here? I don't see a clear description of any issue, aside from an expressed intent to do _something_. wanting to do something isn't a coding problem.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I said that the problem is the files provided are not matched from python and C++

Comment: @AlanBirtles the data input (image) is a float32 type

Comment: @RetiredNinja the saved data to the bin file is "noisyImg" not "data" (it was a typo)

Comment: ok and what does "are not matched" mean in a quantifiable way?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz the size of files is not the same as well as the content (using md5sum to compare between them).

Comment: why do you expect them to be the same? these codes aren't equivalent. did you just copy them from somewhere, without understanding what they do? the C++ code writes some kind of header, the python/numpy code does not. did you even try to look at the file contents with a hex editor?

Comment: I tried to do the same thing provided by the python code as the image is RGB, not grayscale. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes, it is. I checked the pixels type and they are float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

**Updated code**

**Python**

```
filename1 = "./image.bin"   # save data as bin file
bin_file = image.tofile(filename1)
```

**C++**

```
    // Data
    int type = mat.type();
    if (mat.isContinuous())
    {
        fs.write(mat.ptr<char>(0), (mat.dataend - mat.datastart));
    }
    else
    {
        int rowsz = CV_ELEM_SIZE(type) * mat.cols;
        for (int r = 0; r < mat.rows; ++r)
        {
            fs.write(mat.ptr<char>(r), rowsz);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Save data

    {
        cv::Mat Img = cv::imread("image.jpg");
        //randu(m, 0, 5);
        matwrite("bin_file.bin", Img);
    }
return 0 ;
}
```